# Incorrect date value: '' for column 'ххх' at row 1 ( 1292 )

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть таблица в БД, с типом `date` c разрешенным значением `NULL`.
Через страничку администрирования PHP пишу:

```
$date1 = $_POST['date1_input'];
echo $date1;
```

Значение пустое (нулевое).

При вставке

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE record SET dtstamp1='$date1' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);
```

Выходит ошибка:

> Incorrect date value: '' for column 'dtstamp1' at row 1 ( 1292 ).

На странице редактирования разместил инпут с типом дата, т.е. календарь -

```
<input type="date" name = "date1_input" autocomplete="off" value = "">
```

Не могу понять, данные я не ввожу, т.е. дату не выбираю. При проверке значение пустое (нулевое), нулевое значение разрешено. Почему возникает ошибка?

Comment: вот `NULL` туда и вписывайте, а не пустую строку.

Comment: Я не могу определить какое значение получает пустое значение календаря...т.е. незаполненное - NULL или "" или " ". Я вывожу через echo - я меня ничего не выводится.

Comment: А NULL вы в любом случае так не запишите, у вас значение всегда в кавычках, а в запросе должно явно стоять `dtstamp1=NULL` без кавычек. (а `=''` это совершенно не NULL и так нельзя) Вот если бы вы пользовались подготавливаемыми запросами и привязкой переменных, вместо подстановки значений в текст запроса то таких проблем скорее всего бы не было. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php Ну и заодно это не позволило бы первому встречному кулхацкеру заменить вам дату во всей таблице целиком, передав не совсем дату в этом поле

Comment: Запрос UPDATE record SET dtstamp1 = NULL WHERE id=5 LIMIT 1 -  отрабатывает. Как мне преобразовать пустое значение поля в NULL для INSERT или UPDATE? в PHP возможно присвоить переменной значение NULL? Например при проверке - if (empty($date1)){$date1 = NULL;}

Comment: вам уже очевидным образом указали на то. что при получения и прямой подстановке значения `1970-01-01'--`  дата будет заменена во всей таблице. Используйте запросы с параметрами. ссылка была выше.

Answer (score 1):

Если в mysqli всё примерно такое же, как в PDO, то...

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE record SET dtstamp1=? WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);
$stmt->bindParam('si',$date1,$id);
$stmt->execute();
```

И передавайте что хотите. null воспринимается корректно при указании любого из поддерживаемых mysqli типов.

Но главное - надо сначала **проверить, что там передаёт браузер** из "инпута с типом дата", и при необходимости сконвертировать. Потому что браузеры очень любят передавать локализованные значения даты, которые могут очень сильно отличаться от форматов, понимаемых mysql.

P.S. не совсем понял только, зачем получаете результат выполнения этого запроса - какую-то полезную проверку затем делаете? Если нет - перестаньте так делать. Серьезно.